# Using two condition to filter and annotate with if-else in data-frame

Tags: r, dplyr

This is how my data-frame looks like. Due to some issue I can't put `dput` not sure why every time i try `dput(head())` lots of lines coming.

```
head(aaa)
             gene   Symbol   baseMean log2FoldChange     lfcSE      stat       pvalue         padj        H1
1 ENSG00000000003   TSPAN6   22.42144     -3.8726216 0.8384408 -4.618838 3.858959e-06 4.303883e-05  98.40155
2 ENSG00000000419     DPM1  203.90488      0.6564230 0.2562140  2.562011 1.040680e-02 3.520160e-02 213.84905
3 ENSG00000000457    SCYL3  271.83533      0.8711371 0.2576887  3.380579 7.233319e-04 3.846364e-03 103.82526
4 ENSG00000000460 C1orf112  170.67311      0.5257116 0.3205085  1.640243 1.009547e-01 2.082389e-01 155.73789
5 ENSG00000000938      FGR   45.69532      2.0063624 0.7167781  2.799140 5.123891e-03 1.965872e-02  30.99262
6 ENSG00000000971      CFH 2455.30571      1.5569790 1.3289876  1.171553 2.413767e-01 3.930393e-01 884.83918
```

So Im using this long steps to create another column in this dataframe where Im getting the rows which pass `padj < 0.05 and abs(log2FoldChange)`and then which i take further to label `UP` and `DOWN`

This is my code

```
sig_table_hw_oe <- filter(aaa, padj < 0.05 & abs(log2FoldChange) > 1.5)

UP_DOWN_gene <- mutate(aaa, UP_DOWN = ifelse(abs(log2FoldChange)) > 1.5 , "UP", "DOWN")
```

Now how can I combine both of them together and do the same such as I dont want to filter and then add the label to each gene.

I would also want to label those genes as `'NS'` if it doesn't pass `padj < 0.05 and abs(log2FoldChange)`along with `UP and DOWN`

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `case_when`?

```
aaa %>%
  mutate(UP_DOWN = case_when(
    padj < 0.05 & abs(log2FoldChange) > 1.5 ~ "UP", 
    padj < 0.05 & abs(log2FoldChange) < 1.5 ~ "DOWN",
    TRUE ~ 'NS'))

# -------
             gene   Symbol   baseMean log2FoldChange     lfcSE      stat       pvalue         padj        H1 UP_DOWN
1 ENSG00000000003   TSPAN6   22.42144     -3.8726216 0.8384408 -4.618838 3.858959e-06 4.303883e-05  98.40155      UP
2 ENSG00000000419     DPM1  203.90488      0.6564230 0.2562140  2.562011 1.040680e-02 3.520160e-02 213.84905    DOWN
3 ENSG00000000457    SCYL3  271.83533      0.8711371 0.2576887  3.380579 7.233319e-04 3.846364e-03 103.82526    DOWN
4 ENSG00000000460 C1orf112  170.67311      0.5257116 0.3205085  1.640243 1.009547e-01 2.082389e-01 155.73789      NS
5 ENSG00000000938      FGR   45.69532      2.0063624 0.7167781  2.799140 5.123891e-03 1.965872e-02  30.99262      UP
6 ENSG00000000971      CFH 2455.30571      1.5569790 1.3289876  1.171553 2.413767e-01 3.930393e-01 884.83918      NS
```

---

data

```
aaa <- structure(list(gene = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000419", 
"ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938", "ENSG00000000971"
), Symbol = c("TSPAN6", "DPM1", "SCYL3", "C1orf112", "FGR", "CFH"
), baseMean = c(22.42144, 203.90488, 271.83533, 170.67311, 45.69532, 
2455.30571), log2FoldChange = c(-3.8726216, 0.656423, 0.8711371, 
0.5257116, 2.0063624, 1.556979), lfcSE = c(0.8384408, 0.256214, 
0.2576887, 0.3205085, 0.7167781, 1.3289876), stat = c(-4.618838, 
2.562011, 3.380579, 1.640243, 2.79914, 1.171553), pvalue = c(3.858959e-06, 
0.0104068, 0.0007233319, 0.1009547, 0.005123891, 0.2413767), 
    padj = c(4.303883e-05, 0.0352016, 0.003846364, 0.2082389, 
    0.01965872, 0.3930393), H1 = c(98.40155, 213.84905, 103.82526, 
    155.73789, 30.99262, 884.83918)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: That't the right vocabulary  'case_when' thank very much for resolving .. on question how did you get my dataframe to 'dput()'

Comment: I copied the data frame as you posted and then pasted it into this code `aaa <-read.table(text = " ")`

Comment: @nniloc Not everyone uses Windows.

Comment: @nniloc small doubt  'padj < 0.05 & abs(log2FoldChange) < 1.5 ~ "DOWN", this syntax it means anything that is less than 1.5 or -1.5  because i need that is less than -1.5 log2fold change

Comment: `abs(log2FoldChange) < 1.5` would be `TRUE` for values between -1.5 and 1.5. `log2FoldChange < -1.5` would be `TRUE` for values less than -1.5